# Binding in Interfacebuilder clears the prompt text

Tags: objective-c, xcode, binding, interface-builder

As soon as I set up a binding for an `NSTextField` in Interfacebuilder, it clears the placeholder string (The gray text, which disappears as soon as you enter text).

I currently don't understand, why binding the value should change the placeholder string too.

Any ideas?

Comment: Nice find - why don't you write it as an answer yourself, and select is the right one?

Comment: I wanted to do this right away, but I am not allowed to do this, since I don't have enough "respect-points". I did it now, but now I am not able to confirm the solution for another 9 hours... this is somewhat annoying...

Comment: Ah! Well, then you can do it later when you get 'em :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out myself:

As soon as I bind the value to some object I have to use the binding options to re-enable the placeholder string.

In the bindings tab I can now set the value `Null placeholder` which then has the same effect.

I find this a bit confusing but it seems to work.